# "nginx error!" while loading webpage

Tags: nginx, otrs

Background: I've installed and currently maintaining a OTRS v4.0 system with nginx as web server. The system was running until I added ssl port as well in nginx.conf and since then, I'm trying to connect to the webpage

> http://localhost/otrs/index.pl

but is not responsive and displaying *nginx error! The Page you are looking for is not found.*

I removed the ssl sections from the nginx.conf file but still I'm not able to get back my previous state of web page.

- In the error.log file it displays that it is not able to find the index.pl file *open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/otrs/index.pl" failed (2: No such file or directory)*
  This message is logged whenever I hit the URL(http://localhost/otrs/index.pl).
- In the otrs.log file it just logs in the PID.

Is there any way-out without having to re-install the otrs again?  or any other log files I've missed to check

```html
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    #debug_connection 10.0.2.15;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       80;
        server_name  server.unixmen.local;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks rather like a default nginx config file, you will need to look in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` to see whats there, because there's nothing in this file that's configuring `otrs`. Also - this may be offtopic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi. The directory /etc/nginx/conf.d is empty! @Sobrique

Comment: Well, that's why it isn't working then. Because nothing is configured in nginx.

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand the nginx service is active and enabled on the machine. Do I need to re-install nginx? @Sobrique

Comment: You have a base install of nginx there. Usually in `conf.d` is where you add the optional extra stuff. If there is none, you have a 'vanilla' config, with no integration with anything. Which is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. I got the solution!
Perhaps, it was a silly mistake from my end ;)

First of all, I forgot to mention in the question that I also ran another web server on the same machine, Apache. At the initial stage, both the servers were configured at same port ->80. So, the OTRS was running on Apache instead of nginx(I'm using this as well for another purpose!). Later on, to avoid the confusion i changed the port in Apache configuration from 80 to 8080 and right from this moment the server stopped serving the OTRS.
So now, when I use http://localhost:8080/otrs/index.pl it's working correctly.

Next time, I would take enough care to change server configuration wisely while working on multiple web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused your default servers and nginx is trying to serve the wrong content.

OTRS uses fastcgi and will have it's own config file in the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory. The file you have posted is the default nginx config which has little to do with OTRS.

Change your listen directive to:

```
    #listen       80 default_server;
    listen       80;
```

This will discourage the default nginx config from handling unknown host connections to `https://localhost` and assuming it worked previously then the system should work again. If not then post the OTRS config from /etc/nginx/conf.d/something.conf and we'll be able to see what else is happening.

Comment: Hi, tried changing the listen directive. It didn't worked. Also, as mentioned in the previous answer the /etc/nginx/conf.d is empty! @Steve E.

Comment: Interesting. If the site worked before, then there must have been an OTRS specific config somewhere. What about this folder also referenced in your file `/etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf`? Do you have a backup prior to your changes?